# Duplicating fields in Freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

Im building a form in freeform and it is going to contain many state select dropdown fields. Is there any way to duplicate this field so I do not have to populate the options/values manually every time I use that field?

Answer (score 1):

Not manually but you can search for the field in your database. If the plugin uses the normal `craft_fields` you can copy it's settings and paste it in a new record

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Craft Element or Predefined Data feature in Freeform](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/fields-field-types.html#populating-fields-with-elements-predefined-options), you can easily setup options (from Craft Entries, States, Number ranges, etc) for when you're creating additional fields. If you're referring to custom data, if you've created the field through **Freeform** -> **Fields** manager area with the options, you can also duplicate fields from there.